# Hex-Rays decompiles array to int

Tags: c++, arrays, dll, decompiling

I decompiled one dll using Hex-Ray but it decompiled array type input argument of dll to int. Any idea how to handle this ??

```
double dzSell(int a1, double a2, int a3, int a4, int a5)
```

int a1 is array type in dll

Comment: `a1` is not an array. I know that because you can't have arrays as arguments in C.

Comment: i mean that in dll is *double and in pseudocode is int a1

Comment: You are aware that decompilers are very imperfect, right?

Answer (score 0):

here is the example how Hex-Rays decompile pointers

```
/* The computational routine */
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void myfun2 (double x, double *y, double *z, int n)
{
    int i;
    /* multiply each element y by x */
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        z[i] = x * y[i];
    }
}


/*
int __cdecl myfun2(double a1, int a2, int a3, int a4)
{
  int result; // eax@3
  int i; // [sp+0h] [bp-4h]@1

  for ( i = 0; i < a4; ++i )
  {
    *(double *)(a3 + 8 * i) = a1 * *(double *)(a2 + 8 * i);
    result = i + 1;
  }
  return result;
}
*/
```

so clearly pointer variables are converted to int, it means that casting double * -> int must be done as a2 and a3 are used to access the array. For proper casting i used (uintptr_t)buffer