# Hex-rays, MATLAB, MEX, casting uintptr_t fails

Tags: c++, matlab, casting, mex, decompiling

I decompiled some dll using Hex-Rays and than tried to compile it again as MATLAB MEX. As Hex decompiles double * as int and I'm using win 7 64 i casted 
double * using uintptr_t. Unfortunatelly sometimes I'm getting 'segmentation fault' with it.

Here is my code

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <stdint.h>

double __stdcall dzSell(int a1, double a2, int a3, int a4, int a5)
{
  int v5; // ecx@1
  double v6; // st7@3
  double result; // st7@4
  int v8; // ebp@5
  double v9; // st6@5
  double v10; // st5@5
  int v11; // edx@5
  int v12; // esi@6
  int v13; // ecx@6
  double v14; // rt0@10
  double v15; // st5@10
  double v16; // st6@10
  double v17; // rt1@12
  double v18; // rt2@15
  double v19; // st5@15
  double v20; // st6@15
  double v21; // rtt@17
  double v22; // rt0@20
  double v23; // st5@20
  double v24; // st6@20
  double v25; // rt1@22
  double v26; // rt2@25
  double v27; // st5@25
  double v28; // st6@25
  double v29; // rtt@27
  int v30; // esi@29
  int v31; // ecx@29
  double v32; // rt0@33
  double v33; // st5@33
  double v34; // st6@33
  double v35; // rt1@35
  signed int v36; // edi@36
  double v37; // st3@36
  double v38; // st4@36
  double v39; // st2@37
  double v40; // st2@38
  double v41; // rt1@38
  double v42; // st2@38
  double v43; // rt2@38
  signed int v44; // esi@40
  double v45; // st1@40
  int v46; // edx@41
  int v47; // ecx@41
  double v48; // rt0@43
  double v49; // st1@43
  double v50; // st4@43
  double v51; // rtt@45
  double v52; // st5@47
  double v53; // st3@47
  double v54; // rtt@48
  double v55; // rt1@48
  double v56; // st3@48
  double v57; // rt2@48
  double v58; // [sp+4h] [bp-8h]@3
  int v59; // [sp+20h] [bp+14h]@1
  int v60; // [sp+20h] [bp+14h]@5

  v5 = a4 - a5;
  v59 = a4 - a5;
  if ( v59 >= a3 )
    v59 = a3;
  v6 = (double)v59;
  v58 = v6;
  if ( v6 >= 1.0 )
  {
    v8 = v5 - 1;
    v9 = *(double *)(a1 + 8 * (v5 - 1));
    v10 = v9;
    v60 = a1 + 8 * (v5 - 1);
    v11 = 1;
    if ( a3 - 1 < 4 )
    {
LABEL_28:
      if ( v11 < a3 )
      {
        v30 = v8 - v11;
        v31 = a1 + 8 * (v8 - v11);
        do
        {
          if ( v30 < 0 )
            break;
          if ( v10 < *(double *)v31 )
            v10 = *(double *)v31;
          v32 = v10;
          v33 = v9;
          v34 = v32;
          if ( v33 > *(double *)v31 )
            v33 = *(double *)v31;
          ++v11;
          v35 = v33;
          v10 = v34;
          v9 = v35;
          v31 -= 8;
          --v30;
        }
        while ( v11 < a3 );
      }
    }
    else
    {
      v12 = v5 - 4;
      v13 = a1 + 8 * (v5 - 4);
      while ( v12 + 2 >= 0 )
      {
        if ( v10 < *(double *)(v13 + 16) )
          v10 = *(double *)(v13 + 16);
        v14 = v10;
        v15 = v9;
        v16 = v14;
        if ( v15 > *(double *)(v13 + 16) )
          v15 = *(double *)(v13 + 16);
        v17 = v15;
        v10 = v16;
        v9 = v17;
        if ( v12 + 1 < 0 )
          break;
        if ( v10 < *(double *)(v13 + 8) )
          v10 = *(double *)(v13 + 8);
        v18 = v10;
        v19 = v9;
        v20 = v18;
        if ( v19 > *(double *)(v13 + 8) )
          v19 = *(double *)(v13 + 8);
        v21 = v19;
        v10 = v20;
        v9 = v21;
        if ( v12 < 0 )
          break;
        if ( v10 < *(double *)v13 )
          v10 = *(double *)v13;
        v22 = v10;
        v23 = v9;
        v24 = v22;
        if ( v23 > *(double *)v13 )
          v23 = *(double *)v13;
        v25 = v23;
        v10 = v24;
        v9 = v25;
        if ( v12 - 1 < 0 )
          break;
        if ( v10 < *(double *)(v13 - 8) )
          v10 = *(double *)(v13 - 8);
        v26 = v10;
        v27 = v9;
        v28 = v26;
        if ( v27 > *(double *)(v13 - 8) )
          v27 = *(double *)(v13 - 8);
        v11 += 4;
        v29 = v27;
        v10 = v28;
        v9 = v29;
        v13 -= 32;
        v12 -= 4;
        if ( v11 >= a3 - 3 )
          goto LABEL_28;
      }
    }
    v36 = 50;
    v37 = 0.5;
    v38 = (v10 + v9) * 0.5;
    if ( v38 - v9 <= 0.005 )
    {
      result = v38;
    }
    else
    {
      v39 = 0.0;
      while ( v36 > 0 )
      {
        v44 = 0;
        v45 = v39;
        if ( v39 < v6 )
        {
          v46 = v60;
          v47 = v8;
          do
          {
            if ( v47 < 0 )
              break;
            v48 = v45;
            v49 = v38;
            v50 = v48;
            if ( v49 < *(double *)v46 )
              v39 = v39 + 1.0;
            ++v44;
            v46 -= 8;
            --v47;
            v51 = v49;
            v45 = v50;
            v38 = v51;
          }
          while ( (double)v44 < v6 );
        }
        if ( a2 - 0.001 <= v39 / v6 )
        {
          v54 = (v38 + v10) * v37;
          v9 = v38;
          v55 = v37;
          v56 = v10;
          v52 = v55;
          v57 = v56;
          v53 = v54;
          v38 = v57;
        }
        else
        {
          v52 = v37;
          v53 = (v38 + v9) * v37;
        }
        --v36;
        if ( v53 - v9 <= 0.005 )
          return v53;
        v6 = v58;
        v40 = v52;
        v10 = v38;
        v41 = v40;
        v42 = v53;
        v37 = v41;
        v43 = v42;
        v39 = v45;
        v38 = v43;
      }
      result = v38;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    result = 2147483647.0;
  }
  return result;
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {

    double *buffer;
    double Probability;
    int DzLookBackBars;
    int Bars;
    int i;
    double result;

  // Check inputs
  if (nrhs != 5) {//if the user has given anything but one arg, then error
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("Numerical:myGetPr:nrhs", "Require 5 args");
  }
  if (!mxIsNumeric(prhs[0])) {//if input is not numeric (for example a string), then errror
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("Numerical:myGetPr:isnumeric", "Require args that is numeric");
  }

  if(nlhs!=1) {
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:nlhs","One output required.");
  }

  /* make sure the first input argument is type double */
  if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || 
         mxIsComplex(prhs[0])) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notDouble","Input matrix must be type double.");
  }

  // Check output

      int dims[] = {1,1};  //dimensions of output

      buffer =  mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
      Probability =  mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
      DzLookBackBars = mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);
      Bars = mxGetScalar(prhs[3]);
      i = mxGetScalar(prhs[4]);

      result = dzSell ((uintptr_t)buffer, Probability,  DzLookBackBars, Bars, i);

      plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(result);

}
```

and here screens which prove wrong casting

[image]

any idea how to deal with it ???

the example of decompiling arrays by Hex-Rays is here

[Hex-Rays decompiles array to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026068/hex-rays-decompiles-array-to-int?noredirect=1#comment57779133_35026068)

and here is disassembly file

http://www.mediafire.com/view/w82l6somwr7o450/dissasembly.txt

Krzysztof

Comment: The type of `a1` in `dzSell` parameter list is `int`.  Since you are intending to use `uintptr_t`, maybe you should make it that type instead.  You should also modify all related `int` values in that function which are clearly used for "pointer" arithmetic.

Comment: Just a thought, you might be better off trying to compile the assembly into an object file and linking it. Even decompilers for interpreted languages can have trouble, let alone native code ones.

Comment: yes, i changed type at function definition to uintptr_t and it helped but have another segmentation fault in line if ( v10 < *(double *)(v13 + 16) )

Answer (score 1):

Consider the decompiler as giving you a head start, not producing good code.

In particular, the code it creates is not at all portable.  To be able to compile for a different pointer size, you will need to fix the type information.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to use uintptr_t and intptr_t 64 bit integer in both function definition and also inside decompiled function. Decompiled dll was from 32 bit system but my function suppose to work under win 7 64. I used IDA 64 with decompiler but pseudocode generated was 32 bit.

Comment: Well really, the code would be more readable if you used `double*` instead.  You could get rid of all the casts and use array subscripting instead of pointer arithmetic.  Just remember that the decompiled code adds 8 to the address for each element, so `*(double*)(p + 8)` is the same as `((double*)p)[1]`